# Can someone tell me the difference between 別々に and 別々 and 別 and 別に and 別々の

Tags: word-choice, words, synonyms

I am asking for the difference between 別々に and 別々 and 別 and 別に and 別々の.

They are all very similiar having something to do with separate/ly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

別々 is "different from one another", and 別 is "different from what's already mentioned". 別々に means "separately" in the sense of "one by one" or "individually", and you say this when there are many similar things. On the other hand, 別に means "separately" in the sense of "as a different matter" or "independently of existing ones".

- 別々の問題
  many different problems / diverse problems
- 別の問題
  a different problem / a new problem / another problem
- 別々に処理しましょう。
  Let's handle them one by one.
- 別に処理しましょう。
  Let's handle it separately/independently. / Let's handle it as a different issue.
- それは別です。
  That's different (from what has been discussed already).

As for に/の, there is nothing special. You should use the basic rules of no-adjectives; に works adverbially (modifies a verb) and の works attributively (modifies a noun).